# "The directory is not empty" error - using firefox selenium excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, firefox, selenium

I need help with the following error:
[Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZxqo.png)
It keep prompting me "The directory is not empty" when I try to run the following code:

```
Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

Dim By As New By, Assert As New Assert, Verify As New Verify, Waiter As New Waiter

driver.Start "Firefox"
```

I want to run my selenium test on firefox. I am using excel vba to do it. It is workable on Chrome but not on firefox. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SeleniumWrapper is deprecated and no longer supported.
It has been replaced by SeleniumBasic:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases

Usage example:

```
Dim driver As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
driver.Get "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"

driver.FindElementById("searchInput") _
      .SendKeys("champagne") _
      .Submit

driver.Quit
```